# complex numbers structure of Chern classes

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

I have started to read on Chern classes. I cannot quite yet see where the complex numbers and their properties come in as we define Chern classes and other properties. I do see it in later theorems and computation. It seems we could have defined projectivization for any vector bundle for example or even Chern classes. Am I missing something? Where and when do complex field properties really come in?

I am reading Bott and Tu book differential forms in Algebraic Topology. There the construction is based on line bundles and then projectivization and at least in initial steps I do not see any complex field requirement in definitions or proofs. See pp 267 and 270. [https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/botttu.pdf](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/botttu.pdf)

Comment: There are several different ways to set up the theory of Chern classes; it's hard to respond to this question without knowing which one you're using. Can you quote the setup you're looking at?

Comment: Chern classes can be defined for vector bundles on nonsingular algebraic varieties over any field, not just the complex numbers, as done in Grothendieck's *La Théorie des Classes de Chern*. Probably there are even more general definitions than that.

Comment: It's hard to tell, but context suggest that your question is really about the fact that Chern classes are only defined for complex vector bundles, not real bundles. What I'm going to suggest is that you look up Stiefel-Whitney classes. These are the analogous invariants of real vector bundles, with the biggest difference being that they take values in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$-cohomology. This is because complex vector bundles are canonically oriented, which somehow means that their characteristic classes have a somewhat richer theory.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I am reading Bott and Tu book differential forms in Algebraic Topology. There the construction is based on line bundles and then projectivization and at lease in initial things I do not see any complex field need in definitions or proofs.

Comment: @richard D. James yes it seems to follow such a  construction in Bott and Tu text I am reading. https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/botttu.pdf last part of the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For complex line bundles $L$ the first Chern class $c_1(L)$ takes values in $H^2(-, \mathbb{Z})$ and this is quite specific to working over $\mathbb{C}$. One way of thinking about this class is as coming from the exponential sequence

$$1 \to \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{2\pi i} \mathbb{C} \xrightarrow{\exp} \mathbb{C}^{\times} \to 1$$

which induces a long exact sequence with connecting homomorphism $H^1(-, \mathbb{C}^{\times}) \to H^2(-, \mathbb{Z})$; this is exactly the first Chern class. Another way of thinking about this class is as a generator of the cohomology of $\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$, the classifying space of complex line bundles.

Over $\mathbb{R}$ we instead have the first Stiefel-Whitney class $w_1(L)$ of a real line bundle which takes values in $H^1(-, \mathbb{Z}_2)$ and which generates the mod-$2$ cohomology of $\mathbb{RP}^{\infty}$, the classifying space of real line bundles. This comes directly from $\mathbb{R}^{\times}$ being homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{Z}_2$, with no need for a long exact sequence.

Above, $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$, which is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$, satisfies $\pi_0 \cong 1, \pi_1 \cong \mathbb{Z}$, whereas $\mathbb{R}^{\times}$, which is homotopy equivalent to $S^0$, instead satisfies $\pi_0 \cong \mathbb{Z}_2, \pi_1 \cong 1$. So their homotopy is quite different and this leads to the difference in their characteristic classes.

Comment: but if you see Bott and Tu last chapter, you will see even though he speaks of complex field, his fist Chern class does not need anything about complex numbers. Sure, it might be motivated by it but I am wondering if I am missing something and complex numbers are really needed in his construction. It does not appear to me to be so.

Comment: Bott and Tu express the normalization axiom by declaring that for a line bundle $L$, $c_1(L)$  is the Euler class of the real rank $2$ vector bundle obtained by forgetting the complex structure on $L$. There is no analogue of "underlying real bundle of rank $2$" for real line bundles. Do you find this satisfactory?

Comment: @TabesBridges if you see right after that the definition of Chern classes in Bott and Tu, it appears to me to be independent of complex field (a page or tow in the above link after line bundle definition at the last chapter of the book)

Comment: @alireza And to me it does not appear to be independent. You'll need to be much more specific than just making vague references to a book that is already fairly discursive and less-than-organized, especially since the word "complex" appears all over the pages to which you refer.

Comment: @TabesBridges fair enough. To be precise, on page 270 of the text, even though complex is all over the place, the definition of Chern classes appears to be independent of any specific properties of complex fields.

Comment: @alireza I have never encountered $\mathbb P$ of a real vector bundle, and Googling the term doesn't turn up anything, so I don't know the extent to which these things have been studied (other than results that are agnostic regarding the ground field in the first place). As I mentioned in my comment on the question, defining $\mathbb Z$-valued characteristic classes for real vector bundles is problematic due to orientation issues. And it is the coefficient ring that separates Chern classes from the $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$-valued Stiefel-Whitney classes, which you CAN do with real bundles.

Comment: @TabesBridges makes sense. I think, the definition is independent even though he mentions complex field all over the place but for any actual development of that theory, the complex structure is needed.

Comment: @alireza: on page 267 of my edition of Bott and Tu they define the first Chern class of a complex line bundle to be the Euler class of its underlying oriented real plane bundle. This crucially relies on there being an orientation on the underlying real plane bundle (equivalent to saying that the image of $U(1)$ in $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ lands in $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$) and there's no analogue of this fact over $\mathbb{R}$. Bott and Tu need this construction to define the first Chern class of the tautological bundle on page 270.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan " orientation on the underlying real plane" is then the only thing needed ? so if we had an oriented vector bundle we could also define the rest? Also on page 270 of the same text in definition of Chern classes, is orientation the only issue? What is really used from complex fields ?  I guess indirectly orientation is one.

Comment: @alireza: what is needed is to define a certain cohomology class for the tautological line bundle over a projective bundle. Over $\mathbb{C}$ the natural class to define is the first Chern class which takes values in $H^2(\mathbb{P}(V), \mathbb{Z})$ while over $\mathbb{R}$ (in the absence of an orientation) the natural class to define is the first Stiefel-Whitney class which takes values in $H^1(\mathbb{P}(V), \mathbb{Z}_2)$. One way to think about this class is as the $\bmod 2$ Euler class, since every bundle is orientable $\bmod 2$.